# Cambio de imagen al hacer hover con tiempo de transición

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy intentando cambiar una imagen, en especial es el logo de la web... Aparecerá solo en color blanco y al pasar el mouse debe verse el logo a color, para esto use 2 imágenes y el código de abajo, pero ahora el cambio es muy brusco, quisiera cambiar el tiempo en el que hace el cambio o si es posible agregar algún efecto para la transición.

```
<div class="logo">
  <img alt="logo" onmouseout="this.src='img/favicon.webp';" onmouseover="this.src='img/favicon-color.webp';" src="img/favicon.webp" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con un par de lineas de CSS puedes hacer el efecto deseado con transición:

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
}

.div1 .div2 {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.div1:hover .div2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch">
  </div>
</div>
```